# vb6 treeview check if nodes exist if not then add

Tags: vb6, treeview

For some reason, it is not working. The `hostgame.lstUsers` is the TreeView I want to check to see if any of the usernames exist and if it does then ignore and move to next, or else add if it doesn't exist.

You also may realize I have 20 arrays, I don't know of another way to do this as this data can be short or no longer than 20 users' names.

```vb
If InStr(data, "|Lst|") Then
    'Debug.Print data
    Dim PacketArray4d() As String
    PacketArray4() = Split("|Lst|tango|Lst|var|Lst|araz|Lst|james|Lst|Seema", "|Lst|")
    On Error Resume Next
     
    Dim nod As Node
    
    For Each nod In hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes
        Dim inx As Integer
    
        Debug.Print nod
        If nod.Key = PacketArray4(nod.Index) Then    
            'MsgBox "found the key"
        Else
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(1), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(2), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(3), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(4), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(5), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(6), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(7), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(8), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(9), 1
            
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(10), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(11), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(12), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(13), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(14), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(15), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(16), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(17), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(18), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(19), 1
            hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(20), 1
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Main issue lays here I think

```vb
        If nod.Key = PacketArray4(nod.Index) Then
```

post updated

please help clean or fix bugs in the code below

```
If InStr(data, "|Lst|") Then
'Debug.Print data
Dim nod As Node
  Dim PacketArray4d() As String
PacketArray4d() = Split(data, "|Lst|")
On Error Resume Next
 
 
 For i = 0 To UBound(PacketArray4d)
 For Each nod In hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes
   'Debug.Print (PacketArray4d(i))
   If nod.Key = PacketArray4d(i) Then
'Debug.Print nomm & "  top"
'MsgBox "found the key"
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(1), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(2), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(3), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(4), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(5), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(6), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(7), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(8), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(9), 1

hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(10), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(11), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(12), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(13), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(14), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(15), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(16), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(17), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(18), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(19), 1
hostgame.lstUsers.Nodes.Add , , , PacketArray4d(20), 1
Else



End If
Next
Next
 

    With hostgame.lstUsers
        For ixx = 1 To .Nodes.Count
            For j = .Nodes.Count To (ixx + 1) Step -1
                If .Nodes(j) = .Nodes(ixx) Then
                    .Nodes.Remove j
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
 End If
```

Comment: `You also may realize I have 20 arrays` - you have one array, `PacketArray4d() As String`, which remains empty because you fill `PacketArray4` instead.

Comment: post updated please check

Comment: Have you stepped through this code to see what happens and which line causes an issue?